# Angular: How to drop a line by the number of characters in the message?

Tags: angular

This is an illustration image:
[image]

I want after a certain amount of characters to go down a line in the text.

I tried to do it in html:

```
<div *ngIf="msgText.length > 30">
      <br>
    </div>
```

But it's not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS using [`word-break: break-all;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) if actual character count doesn't matter and you just want to break words up based on the container size. This requires that you have a width on the container element.

> `break-all`
>
> To prevent overflow, word breaks should be inserted between any two characters (excluding Chinese/Japanese/Korean text).

```css
.split-text {
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-text">
  BlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlah
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine but it destroys me the rest of the css if I set it to be in the direction of ltr it is shown to me in the middle

Comment: In the end I somehow changed the width and it worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe to do that:

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'wrapLine' })
export class WrapLinePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, length = 30): string {
    return [value.slice(0, length), value.slice(length)].join('<br>');
  }
}
```

```html
<p [innerHTML]="someVariable | wrapLine"></p>
```

See [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/wrap-line-with-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwrap-line.pipe.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It's a bad practice to parse html for XSS, better with text\n and white-space: pre-line;